# How to reset index in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from which I remove some rows. As a result, I get a dataframe in which index is something like `[1,5,6,10,11]` and I would like to reset it to `[0,1,2,3,4]`. How can I do it?

---

The following seems to work:

```py
df = df.reset_index()
del df['index']
```

The following does not work:

```py
df = df.reindex()
```

Comment: Not a duplicate. A different question that happens to have the same answer.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate of a related question but that one is about retaining the index as a column while this one is about resetting the index altogether which, although subtle, makes it different imo.

Answer (score 1125, accepted):

[`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) is what you're looking for. If you don't want it saved as a column, then do:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you don't want to reassign:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Instead of reassign the dataframe to the same variable you can set `inplace=True` argument.

Comment: Note that in case of `inplace=True` the method returns None

Comment: This solved my problem of incurring in ValueError: cannot insert level_0, already exists while using df = df.reset_index() multiple times

Comment: @mkln, I have increased in both columns (even with `drop =True`) and rows. `df.reset_index()` only fixed the rows. Can be used to fix the columns as well?

Comment: Why would we want to reset the index if we are going to drop it anyway?

Comment: @Victor - If you don't "drop" the index, it will add a new index, and save the old index values as a series in your dataframe

Comment: Which is better and fast?

Answer (score 73):

Another solutions are assign `RangeIndex` or `range`:

```
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))

df.index = range(len(df.index))
```

It is faster:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[8,7], 'c':[2,4]}, index=[7,8])
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)
print (df.head())

In [298]: %timeit df1 = df.reset_index(drop=True)
The slowest run took 7.26 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 105 µs per loop

In [299]: %timeit df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))
The slowest run took 15.05 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.84 µs per loop

In [300]: %timeit df.index = range(len(df.index))
The slowest run took 7.10 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: @Outcast Source - The fastest is `len(df.index)`, 381ns vs `df.shape` 1.17us. Oyr something missing?

Comment: This is an elegant solution to reset the index. Thank you! I found out that if you try to convert an hdf5 object to pandas.DataFrame object, you have to reset the index before you can edit certain sections of the DataFrame.

Comment: Does the timing change much if you do `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` to avoid the copy?

Answer (score 24):

```
data1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.reset_index(drop=True)` effectively replaces the index by the default RangeIndex. Another way to do the same thing is to straight away assign a new index using `set_axis()` (which I believe is what OP attempted with `reindex`). So the following two return the same output:

```py
df1 = df.set_axis(range(len(df)))

df2 = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Note that most method/functions in pandas that remove/modify rows such as `drop_duplicates()`, `sort_values()`, `dropna()`, `pd.concat()` etc. have `ignore_index` parameter, which when passed True resets the index into a RangeIndex in a single function call. So keep an eye out for this parameter if you were removing/adding rows to a dataframe. An example:

```py
df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)    # <--- instead of this

df.dropna(ignore_index=True)          # <--- use this
```

In this way, you can use `inplace` parameter as well.

```py
df1 = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)     # <--- must assign to dataframe
df.dropna(ignore_index=True, inplace=True)   # <--- `df` modified in-place
```

If you used `groupby` and want to replace the index into the default RangeIndex, there is the `as_index` parameter when passed False resets the index into RangeIndex in the same function call. So instead of `df.groupby('col1').mean().reset_index()`, use `df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).mean()`.