# Pandas reset index is not taking effect

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, reset

I'm not sure where I am astray but I cannot seem to reset the index on a dataframe.

When I run `test.head()`, I get the output below:

[image: test.head]

As you can see, the dataframe is a slice, so the index is out of bounds.
What I'd like to do is to reset the index for this dataframe. So I run `test.reset_index(drop=True)`. This outputs the following:

[image: reset]

That looks like a new index, but it's not. Running `test.head` again, the index is still the same. Attempting to use `lambda.apply` or `iterrows()` creates problems with the dataframe.

How can I really reset the index?

Comment: i'm sorry but those tables are...  such... such huge images. @_@ I was cracking up.

Comment: @kuanb You'll be happy to know the tables are reformatted in Jupyter notebook 5 :)

Comment: It's against SO guidelines to post data-as-image, please rewrite with data as text.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

BrenBarn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27736280/7758804) works.

The following also worked via [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490274/how-to-reset-index-in-a-pandas-data-frame), which isn't a troubleshooting so much as an articulation of how to reset the index:

```
test = test.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 73):

[`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) by default does not modify the DataFrame; it returns a *new* DataFrame with the reset index.  If you want to modify the original, use the `inplace` argument: `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`.  Alternatively, assign the result of `reset_index` by doing  `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`.

Answer (score 4):

As an extension of [in code veritas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573069/in-code-veritas)'s answer... instead of doing `del` at the end:

```
test = test.reset_index()
del test['index']
```

You can set drop to `True`.

```
test = test.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add to in code veritas's answer:

If you already have an index column specified, then you can save the del, of course. In my hypothetical example:

```
    df_total_sales_customers = pd.DataFrame({'Sales': total_sales_customers['Sales'],
                              'Customers': total_sales_customers['Customers']}, index = total_sales_customers.index)

    df_total_sales_customers = df_total_sales_customers.reset_index()
```