# Problem converting Xarray Dataset to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, python-xarray

I have a problem converting a Xarray dataset into a Pandas dataframe.
The thing is that when I convert into a pd dataframe, pandas don't see the right amount of columns. During the conversion I switch from 5 columns (lat, lon, time, sst, time_bnds) to only 2 columns.

Here is my code

```
PATH = os.path.join (DIR, 'sst.mnmean.nc')
data=xr.open_dataset(PATH)
```

[image: I'm not able to copy paste the result so here is a screenshot]

```
data_pd = data.to_dataframe(dim_order=None)
```

[image: Here is the result in pandas dataframe]

As you can see pandas sees only 2 columns even though there are 6 variables.

I was expecting to see the 5 exact same columns in my pandas dataframe, which is not the case. To be clear, **I just want to work with sst variable (sea surface temperature) and time bnds which is the timestamp**

*(I know that coordinates are considered as index, I tried `reset_index()` but it doesn't work)*

Comment: This is a bit hard for us to debug without more info. Ideally, you could post a full [mre] but at least could you copy and paste the results of `print(data)` and `print(data_pd)` into your question as a text block?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the post. I hope it's clearer

Comment: You can copy the result of print(ds) - it’s a string. Please fully upload images of data/code/logs/etc

Comment: reset_index does work, but it's not an inplace operation, so try `data_pd = data_pd.reset_index()`. the other variables are just in the index - they're not columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas reset index is not taking effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736267/pandas-reset-index-is-not-taking-effect)