# Creating to just be incrementally increasing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with lots of rows

```
0  val1
1  val2
2  val3
3  val3
4  val4
5  nan
6  nan
7  val7
```

I drop the na values I am left with:

```
0  val1
1  val2
2  val3
3  val3
4  val4
7  val7
```

However, now if I iterate over this doing something like:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    row = df.at[1, 'colname']
```

I get an index error.  I need to reindex it so it becomes like:

```
0  val1
1  val2
2  val3
3  val3
4  val4
5  val7
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: I think need https://stackoverflow.com/q/20490274/2901002

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset index in a pandas data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490274/how-to-reset-index-in-a-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: If you're going to iterate through your dataframe, it might also be useful to look into `df.iterrows()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you need to preserve the old index or not. If you do *not* want to preserve it, use one of the solutions offered in the comments (e.g. `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`) and your original code.

If you want to preserve the old index, then you have to use it correctly:

```
for i in df.index:
    row = df.loc[i, 'colname']
```