# Dataframe.reset_index() doesn't work on after concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

There are two other similar questions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490274/how-to-reset-index-in-a-pandas-dataframe), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461165/how-to-convert-index-of-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-column); but none helped me in my issue.

I did concat several columns of `df` at the beginning and at the end of `df_new`. The indexing has increased and I don't find a way to fix this with [df.reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd

print("1- df: ", len(df.index),len(df.columns),"\n")
print("1- df_new: ", len(df_new.index),len(df_new.columns),"\n")

# Adding 5 columns at the begininig and 2 columns at the end of df_new from df
df_new = pd.concat([df[df.columns[0:self.x_col_start]], df_new], axis =1)
df_new = pd.concat([df_pca, df[df.columns[self.y_col:]]], axis =1)
print("2- df: ", len(df.index),len(df.columns),"\n")
print("2- df_new: ", len(df_new.index),len(df_new.columns),"\n")

# Resetting df_new
df_pca.reset_index(level=df_pca.index.names, drop=True, inplace=True)
print("3- df: ", len(df.index),len(df.columns),"\n")
print("3- df_new: ", len(df_new.index),len(df_new.columns),"\n")
```

---

```
Output:

1- df: 32770, 178
1- df_new: 32770, 15

2- df: 32770, 178
2- df_new: 61441, 22

3- df: 32770, 178
3- df_new: 61441, 22
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

After spending hours to debug my code, I found out that `df` hadbeen already modified in the previous blocks of code and thus, the indices needed to be reset before being used here. Lessons learned.

Always do

```
# drop=True for not adding the index column to the df
# inplace=True for updating df inplace without copying to another object. 
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

**before** you do further manipulations, otherwise, debugging will be a nightmare at the end.