# How to index by value, group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying analyze the rates of high blood pressure in different diagnosis of diabetes with that of healthy individuals.
The output I am getting is this:

```
0     0.371132
8     0.752674
64    0.629022
```

The output I need is this

```
Diabetes_012    average HBP occurence
0               0.371132
2               0.752674
1               0.629022
```

Where the output index is the diabetes types and the value is the average occurrence of diabetes.

Here is the full code

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv ('diabetes_012_health_indicators_BRFSS2015.csv') 
df2=df.copy
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
grouped=df.groupby(['Diabetes_012'])['HighBP'].transform('mean').drop_duplicates()
print(grouped)
```

Here is the link to the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/alexteboul/diabetes-health-indicators-dataset

Comment: just  added the link

Comment: `grouped.reset_index(drop=True)` should do the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset index in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490274/how-to-reset-index-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No that does not make the index equivalent to the  type of diabetes, the value of 2 and 1 are swapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.transform`, just grab the column (or columns) on which you want to perform the mean:

```py
In [3]: df.groupby("Diabetes_012")[["HighBP"]].mean()
Out[3]:
                HighBP
Diabetes_012
0.0           0.371132
1.0           0.629022
2.0           0.752674
```

Example with multiple columns:

```py
In [4]: df.groupby("Diabetes_012")[["HighBP", "BMI"]].mean()
Out[4]:
                HighBP        BMI
Diabetes_012
0.0           0.371132  27.742521
1.0           0.629022  30.724466
2.0           0.752674  31.944011
```